# Review flags 'stuck'?

Tags: support, bug, review

For the past week or so every time I look at the review queue I see two queues red flagged - i.e. 'too many, please rush to clean up.'

The thing is, I've cleared all my queues, empty, nada, nothing left to do.

The flags still show.

[image]

I can only assume I've found a bug, how do we go about dealing with it?

Comment: I remember this happened a while ago, and there are posts about it on meta.se. That issue had been resolved though. Posts tagged bug do get seen by the SE team so will no doubt respond with a fix or workaround

Answer (score 0):

Well… as if my magic, today they're gone.

Back to normal.

I'll wait a day or three to see if this gets tagged as status-completed.

*Late edit*
Well… a year later & it's still doing it. I've just learned to ignore it now.